# What type of Resource is a Popup Menu in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, menu

I've been researching popup menus (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647626(v=vs.85).aspx) and a bit confused at what they are behind the scenes.

They act partially like windows, but look like controls. For instance, they pop up above other elements, steal focus, and can go outside their parent container which makes me think they are a type of window. But they pass back an HMENU handle instead of a window handle, and they have no title bar, nor handles, nor show up in the task bar.

If they are a type of control, how can they go outside their parent window?

If they are a type of window, can I use window-specific functions on them? or if they are a control in a new window, is there a way to get a win handle to that new window?

Can I get the location of the popup menu for another application?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a *parent* and an *owner*. A child window is confined by its parent's client area, an owned window can grow beyond its owner's client area. A ComboBox control is clearly a control. Its dropdown list (also a control) can render outside its parent's client area. The dropdown list, however, is not a child window, but owned. Your conclusions are based on wrong assumptions, ill-fated, and won't solve your problem. [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), however, will.

Comment: This seems to list dialogs, popup menus, the desktop, and icons are all listed as `windows` here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system

Comment: Of course! Everything you see on your screen is essentially hosted inside a window, be it an application's main window, a control, a dialog, or even a fullscreen DirectX/OpenGL app. I'm just saying that your distinction between a window and a control is completely wrong. Some windows have the `WS_CAPTION` window style, others don't. This is not a differentiating feature. The same goes for the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`, and so on. Read [Window Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) to get a **basic** understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

[trying to get a handle to a context menu in c++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a54fbe2a-ab40-4e78-b15b-42289b585142/trying-to-get-a-handle-to-a-context-menu-in-c)

Looks like a menu is a type of window, that is a child of the desktop window. You can get its window handle with `EnumChildWindows` on the desktop WinHandle and look for the class name of `#32768`.

There's more about these reserved system windows here:

[About Window Classes | System Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system)

Answer (score 0):

A popup menu is a [menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms647553), not a window.

A menu merely uses a window for display.  A *new* window is created each time the menu is displayed, and is destroyed afterward.  By contrast, the same HMENU can be used to display the menu many times.